# How can I get Ubuntu on my old (Verity VL Series) laptop?

Tags: laptop

I was cleaning out my old bedroom (I haven't lived in for 10 years) and I found my old Verity VL Series Laptop. It had been recovered after a boyfriend had stolen/traded it for his drug habit, and long story short it was recovered but along the line someone couldn't get past my BIOS password so the OS was removed completely. It used to run Windows 95 but that's pretty obsolete. I'd love to run Ubuntu on it (Used to have another computer in which I ran Ubuntu along side it to try it out). The only problem I seem to be having is getting it on there. It has a CD drive, and I downloaded Ubuntu Desktop, then burned it to a disk using PowerISO. I stuck it in and made sure the BIOS would boot from the CD drive, then the hard drive. It seems to be getting stuck right after it says it is going to load the logo, and now is stuck on selecting a language... Am I on the right track or are these 'getting stuck' moments signs it would be too much for this laptop? I really don't know a lot about it, how big the hard drive is, what video cards are in it, or anything. If anyone can help it would be wonderful!

Thanks!

Edit: After it was stuck on the Language Selection, I came to ask the question here. In the time it took me to write this it stated:

"This kernel requires the following features not present on the CPU:

pae cmov

Unable to boot - please use a kernel appropriate for your CPU."

???

Comment: Does that lap have the minimum required configurations? (5GB of Had disk space and 384MB of RAM?)

Answer (score 1):

Here's an article on how to install 12.04 in your use case:

http://www.webupd8.org/2012/05/how-to-install-ubuntu-1204-on-non-pae.html

The default install is looking for Physical Address Extension (PAE) capabilities in your computer that in that vintage didn't have such capabilities.

The leads you through the steps of installation with a PAE kernel.